# What is changing the network interfaces?

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, nfs

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 to virtual machine. I have edited `/etc/network/interfaces` like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Then I created a livecd.iso using relinux. Network interfaces is changing after boot from DVD (livecd.iso).

`/etc/network/interfaces` after boot from DVD:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
auto wlan1
iface wlan1 inet dhcp
```

But It is changing different if I boot livecd.iso via NFS.

`/etc/network/interfaces` after boot via NFS(Network File System):

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
auto wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
```

I'm really confused. What is changing the network interfaces? How can I prevent the changes?

Answer (score 1):

eth0, eth1, etc are friendly name to a more complicated device ID. So if you take a configuration and run it against different hardware, you get a new name because eth0 is still linked to the original device id. I'm not familiar with what relinux does. But that is the gist.

Check the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` this contains the device Ids (mac address) mapping to device names (eth0, eth1).

If you delete this file before doing your iso, it should be recreated each time and thus would make the first network device found, eth0.

Comment: I checked `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`, it is empty. I deleted it and created live cd again, same thing happened